# Regex not stopping where I think it should

Tags: php, regex

I can't figure out why this is not stopping where I thought it should.

Here is the example string.

```
<div class="blah"><a href="www.foo.bar">foo bar</a></div>
<div class="blah2"><span><a href="www.bar.foo">bar foo</a></span></div>
```

This grouping repeats itself over and over so I'm using the following.

```
preg_match('@<div class="blah">.*</span></div>@', $page, $matches);
```

It works but gets every single grouping at once instead of one at a time.  Am I missing something simple here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
<div class="blah">.*?</span></div>
```

`.*` matches greedily, so it will encapsulate as much as it can within that `.*` before matching the rest of the regex.  `.*?` matches reluctantly, so it matches as little as possible before continuing to the rest of the regex.

Comment: Thank you. 1 character, I should have known! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use the `U` (`PCRE_UNGREEDY`) option, which makes by default all searches ungreedy :

```
preg_match('@<div class="blah">.*</span></div>@U', $page, $matches);
```